# VMWare Bridged Connection Has Lost Network Connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware

I am running VMWare Product: VMware Workstation 12 Pro Version: 12.0.1 build-3160714 and have been for about the past year, and today when I fire up one of my VM's my Bridged connection no longer is able to connect.  The host machine has internet/network no problem, and 2 other VM's are able to connect no problem, but this one machine is giving me issues all of a sudden.  Here is a screenshot of the settings[image: Settings] - what do I need to do in order to get the Bridged Connection functioning again?

Comment: Is the guest configured to use a static IP address or DHCP?  If static, is there a possibility of an IP address conflict?  If DHCP, does the guest manage to successfully acquire a valid IP address?  With bridged networking, provided that your host has working connectivity, usually it's going to be a problem either in the guest or with your router and virtualization isn't likely to be involved (i.e., you should be troubleshooting it as you would for a physical machine).

Comment: It's a Static IP.  No IP Conflict.  Thanks for the tip, I'll troubleshoot as I would a physical machine and see what I can come up with.